# How do I value bind multiple case statements in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, enums

I'm learning Swift 2

I have this code:

```
case .Login(let parameters):
    return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
case .GetUpComingRides(let parameters):
    return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

There is a lot of redundancy. I have tried this:

```
case .Login(let parameters), .GetUpComingRides(let parameters):
    return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

But I'm getting the warning of `immutable value 'parameters' was never used`;

How do I check for multiple case statements and get the values?

I feel that I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I bind different associated values in a Swift enum to the same var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827507/can-i-bind-different-associated-values-in-a-swift-enum-to-the-same-var)

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Swift, this is now possible if the values are of the same type:

```swift
enum Foo {
    case bar(Int),  bas(Int)
}

var this = .random() ? Foo.bar(5) : Foo.bas(5)
switch this {
    case .bar(let foo), .bas(let foo): print(foo) // Always prints 5
}
```